# Wijmo and Dotnetnuke 7. Has anyone tried it? Not working

Tags: dotnetnuke, wijmo

Has anyone tried using the wijmo widgets in DNN 7.+ ?

For my example I'm trying to use the upload widget.

1. If I upload to a path on my server and test, it works (As in the dialog appears to choose a file... the popup)
2. If I load it within a page on the site, the button shows but nothing happens when clicked.

All script files and necessary markup are correct.

No console erros, nothing. Very confusing.

Comment: I would start by checking which version of jquery your local DNN install is using, perhaps there is a conflict between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Wijmo widgets work in DNN 7.+.

The “action” option should be changed to the server’s address of upload.ashx file.
Note: the upload sample can’t be opened by file path(d:/……/upload.html), please make sure it is opened on server.

Thanks,
Richa